# Printing an array or object in Ruby on rails. Also view the structure of the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, puts

I'm executing an Active Record query in controller. And now I want to view all of its contents weather it is in the form of array or object. I want to see the structure in which the data is being returned. I'm new to ruby on rails. In PHP we use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

Comment: You can use rails c (rails console) and see sql query along with returned data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this doc, 'Debugging Rails Applications', particularly section 3, 'Debugging with ruby-debug':
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Oh .. how comes i didn't see it. Thanks for the link that's what i wanted.

Comment: -1 for link-only answer. You should quote the pertinent content in your answer to avoid irrelevancy if/when link rot occurs.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of ways to do this. If you want to play with the result interactively, open the rails console by typing `rails console`. Run the query you want in the console

```
query_result = MyModel.find_by_interesting_parameter( 'Foo' )
```

Then use the `to_yaml` method to dump a nice structure out

```
puts query_result.to_yaml
```

Sometimes, it's just easier to see what the view has had back. To do this, use the `debug` method in the view itself...

```
<%= debug @post %>
```

See this page [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

Try the `to_yaml` and the `inspect` methods.